# Ajax future single post query doesn't work when NOT logged in

Tags: wp-query, ajax, wpdb

I am having a problem with an ajax request for a single post, when the user is not logged in. The post is a calendar date and is in the future. the query works fine if I am logged into wordpress but doesn't when I am logged out. This type of query also works when there is no ajax involved, for example if I want to display all future dates in a category page. Do I need to fire up an instance of wpdb to get the results? Must be a permission thing but cant find any answers.

```
function ajax_get_date_post() 
{
    // get the submitted parameters
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mandy_dates',
        'p' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'future,publish'
    );

    // build and make query
    $clicked_date =  new WP_Query( $args );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/html" );
    if ( $clicked_date->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $clicked_date->have_posts() ) {
            $clicked_date->the_post();
            include( $this->get_single_post_template_path() );
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, Date not found";
    }

    exit;
}
```

UPDATE:

these are the hooks:

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_get_date_post', array(&$this, "ajax_get_date_post") );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_get_date_post', array(&$this, "ajax_get_date_post") );
```

this is the Ajax JS:

```
function ajax_get_post( _id ) 
{
    $.post(
        mandy_dates_js_config.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'ajax_get_date_post',
            post_id : _id
        },
        function( response ) {
            on_date_loaded( response );
        }
    );
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I figured it out. modified the "show-future-posts-on-single-post" to work in my ajax request, here the updated code

```
function ajax_get_date_post() 
{
    // get the submitted parameters
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mandy_dates',
        'p'         => $post_id
        // 'post_status' => 'future,publish'
    );

    // build and make query
    $this->clicked_date = new WP_Query();

    add_filter( 'the_posts', array( &$this,'show_future_posts') );
    $this->clicked_date->query( $args );
    remove_filter( 'the_posts', array(&$this,'show_future_posts') );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/html" );
    if ( $this->clicked_date->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $this->clicked_date->have_posts() ) {
            $this->clicked_date->the_post();
            include( $this->get_single_post_template_path() );
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, Date not found";
    }

    exit;
}

function show_future_posts( $posts )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if( $this->clicked_date->post_count == 0 ) {
        $posts = $wpdb->get_results($this->clicked_date->request);
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem is outside this function?

Comment: i logged the query and the object is right, just the posts array is empty, as soon as I am logged in it works perfectly.

Comment: I think it might have something to do that the posts are in the future. it works perfect as soon as the posts are from the past. there is this plugin (http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/show-future-posts-on-single-post/trunk/show-future-posts-on-single-post.php ) which seems to fix the problem by using wpdb, but since its an ajax request I don't have all the parameters for wpdb available, such as db_username and pass.

Answer (score 3):

usually it because you are missing an "add_action" call for none logged in users.

add this to your plugin or functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_REPLACETHIS', 'ajax_get_date_post');
```

and change the REPLACETHIS to your action value from the ajax call.

remember that when calling ajax from front-end and you want to allow none logged in users
to make these calls you allways add both:

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

you can read about more at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: yes sorry should have mentioned that I did this. the function gets called I can evel log wp query and see that all the parameters are set its just that the posts in wp_query array is empty.

Comment: paste you ajax code and your ajax hooks code so i could get a better idea.

Comment: thanks pasted above. I think the reason why it doesn't work is because the posts are in the future. it works perfectly when I am  logged out with dates which are in the past. it only works logged in when the queried posts are in the future. thats the only difference between it working and not working.

Comment: have you tried using "global $wpdb;" ?

Comment: thanks בניית אתרים. i figured it out, you are right there is an instance of wpdb already even in an ajax request

Comment: glad it worked out :)